# How to center header text in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

How to center header text in pandas dataframe with command df.head()? Now the align is in the right, how to change this?
Im using Python 3.6 in jupyterlab 1.0

The code :

```
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
```

dont work for df.head() command. Alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
```

[`option docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)

**Here is an example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.random.randn(6),
                             np.random.randint(1, 9, 6) * .1,
                             np.zeros(6)]).T,
                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='float')
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
print(df)

       A      B    C 
0 -0.600705  0.5  0.0
1 -0.195192  0.6  0.0
2 -1.227175  0.8  0.0
3  0.625125  0.7  0.0
4 -0.455949  0.3  0.0
5 -0.809112  0.7  0.0
```

Comment: But if i write : 
           df.head() 
dont change nothing